# html multiple functions for "onkeypress" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, function, onkeypress

I have this HTML text input as below

```
<label style="color: white;" for="id">ID:</label>
            <input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" maxlength="9" name="id" id="id">
```

Now, in the onkeypress I successfully added so only numbers can be entered.
but I have a JavaScript function called:

```
function checkID() {
```

and I want that additionally, after every number entered it will call this function. But I just can't get it to do them both (only allow numbers and call the function).

Thanks in advance! Itay.

Comment: could you share with us how to you call this function ? do you do something like : `onkeypress="checkId()"` ? in that case why do you don't recover the event in your function and test the number by beggining your function with `if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the number validation to the `checkID` function.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return checkID(event,this)" maxlength="9" name="id" id="id">

function checkID(e,elem) {
    if !(e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57)
        return false;
    // continue checking the id...
}
```

Comment: It worked! but for some reason it does my code that inside my function only after one character. for example when typed "2" it does a check for "" when the input is "29" it does the check for "2". and so on.. is there a way to fix that or is that just too much to ask?

Comment: try `onkeyup` instead `onkeypress`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to attaching your function via html, you can add it using purely javascript:

```
document.querySelector("your-html-selector").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { 
    // all your code here
});
```

This keeps your html clean and your code easy to read, especially if you're trying to execute multiple functions and such on an event occurring.